# JUnit test failing although expected exception is thrown

Tags: java, testing

I can't seem to figure out why one of my tests is failing.

Here's the test:

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void complainsIfFromLocIsDifferentObject() throws Throwable {
    board.set(make(), 1, 3); //Creates different rook from 'piece'
    assertFalse("ChessPiece Test 2", piece.isValidMove(getValidMove(1, 3), board));
}
```

I've set a breakpoint and gone through the process multiple times. It goes into the second if-statement in the `ChessPiece` class, and seems to throw the exception. The process then goes back to the `Rook` class and returns false under the `super` block.

Any ideas as to what's happening? Thanks

Relevant code:

```
public class Rook extends ChessPiece {

    @Override
    public boolean isValidMove(Move m, IChessBoard b) {
        if (super.isValidMove(m, b) == false)
            return false;

        // Add logic specific to rook
        if(m.fromRow == m.toRow || m.fromColumn == m.toColumn)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
}


public abstract class ChessPiece implements IChessPiece {

    @Override
    public boolean isValidMove(Move m, IChessBoard b) {

        //Verify that there is a piece at the origin
        if (b.pieceAt(m.fromRow,m.fromColumn) == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        // Verify that this piece is located at move origin
        IChessPiece piece = b.pieceAt(m.fromRow, m.fromColumn);
        if (this != piece)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
     }
}
```

Comment: It's very hard to understand what's going on from *just* the partial code you've given. Can you simplify it to a short but *complete* example? And if you're expecting `isValidMove` to throw an exception, why would you *also* have an assertion (which you won't reach)?

Comment: Oh, and your `ChessPiece.isValidMove` implementation is invalid code - it doesn't return anything. That suggests you're not running the code you've posted.

Comment: What does the testfailure say?

Comment: @Jon Sure, I skimped because I didn't want pages of code. This is a game of chess. What's happening is I'm testing my move method. I'm placing a brand new rook at a position and then trying to move a different 'piece' from that position.

I'm not sure why the assertion is there, the test was provided by my instructor. And that is not the complete ChessPiece.isValidMove, just parts relevant to this test.

Comment: @JensSchauder I get "java.lang.AssertionError:Expected exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> It goes into the second if-statement in the ChessPiece class, and
>   seems to throw the exception. The process then goes back to the Rook
>   class and returns false under the super block.

What is happening is the first line in the `isValidMove()` of `Rook` class calls `super` method so control goes there, but due to the condition of second `if` not being met it throws `IllegalArgumentException` and then control returns back to child class ie `Rook` and it cannot `return false` now as super has thrown an exception so the exception will be re thrown outside from this method and will be re-thrown from junit `complainsIfFromLocIsDifferentObject` method.

This will be understood by JUnit framework and should pass the test case.

Check if you have this line `@RunWith(value = BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` at the test case class.

**UPDATE:**

```
@RunWith(value = BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class Test extends TestCase{

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void test1() throws Throwable{
        assertFalse(throwException());
    }

    private boolean throwException(){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

This test case passes for me.

Comment: I do not have @RunWith(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class) at the test case class. When I add it I get an error saying "The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type RunWith"

What is that attempting to do, anyway?

Comment: `@RunWith(value = BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` use this instead

Comment: can you try to execute the example I gave in my post? Also based on your comment I get `Assertion Error Exception expected` , I guess somewhere there is a `try{}catch{}` block which is catching the exception and returning false instead of throwing exception. Check for that too.

Comment: Thanks to running your example class I figured out the problem. There was no notification before, but after attempting to run your test and receiving a ClassNotFoundException, I got a notification telling me something was wrong with the build path. Problem solved, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

As you write in a comment JUnit tells you what is wrong:

> I get "java.lang.AssertionError:Expected exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

You get an AssertionError, probably from an assertion before the expected exception gets thrown or because the Exception gets handled and then an assertion executed which fails.

If you remove the 'expected' value from the annotation JUnit will give you the exact location where the assertion failed (a.k.a. stacktrace)

Answer (score -1):

Usually I'd not put JUnit assertions around code that I expect the exception to throw.

So

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException)
public void test() {
   board.set(make(), 1, 3); //Creates different rook from 'piece'
   piece.isValidMove(getValidMove(1, 3), board);
}
```

Otherwise the exception is thrown within the JUnit assert statement which wraps the exception in an assertionException.

Comment: In the tag `@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException)` value of expected needs to be constant. So this is not right way of using @Test. The correct way is `@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)`